# TransitionManager и вложенные ViewGroup

Tags: android, transition

По клику одной из кнопок меняется набор кнопок и некоторые делали в каждом конкретном view в списке. Анимация на `AutoTransition`, без изысков. Я это сделал, это работает, но мне не нравится как =) Сейчас я делают следующее:

1. ViewGroup с кнопками под списком запускаю `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(view)`, после чего делаю необходимые изменения применением нужного `ConstrainSet`
2. Для каждого активного viewHolder-а в списке так же вызываем `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(view)`, применяем нужный `ConstraintSet`

В итоге запускается множество анимаций в количестве %число видимых элементов%+1, и я весьма уверен, что это плохой подход. Но я не могу понять как заставить анимироваться вложенные друг в друга viewGroup. `Targets` в `Transition` явно не для этого, через сцены я не представляю как это должно выглядеть...

В общем, вопрос: как анимировать через  `Transition` вложенные друг в друга `ViewGroup`?